# What does X(1:n, 1) mean in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

In a sample code I have X(1:n, 1)
I don't understand how it works

n=3 in a sample

Is it a matrix? but isn't () used for indexing so how it's a double index?

Comment: If `X` is a matrix, `X(i, j)` refers to the `i`th row and `j`th column. `X(1:n, 1)` refers to the first through nth rows, and the first column. This is covered in any basic tutorial on matrix indexing and slicing in Matlab. Questions as basic as this usually indicate the need for a tutorial or to talk to a tutor in person. Please note that Stack Overflow is not a replacement for tutorials. Please take the [tour] and read [what's on-topic here](/help/on-topic), [ask], and the [question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953). Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: _Is it a matrix?_ How can we know? Only you can tell us. The syntax `X(1:n, 1)` could also be a function accepting two inputs; or a 2D cell array being indexed; or a table being indexed

Answer (score 1):

I imagine that your `X` is a two-dimmensional matrix. Generalizing, it can be said that to access the elements of a matrix is done with: `X(n,m)`.

The common case is to get one single number, in that case `n` and `m` are integer numbers. But you can also pass vectors to `n` and `m` positions and that way extract a submatrix from the original one.

As an example:

```
X = [1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9]

X(1:3,1) = [1; 4; 7]
```